# How to get user profile on Google API using the JAVA library?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-api, google-api-java-client, userinfo

I have a Java ClientRequest to the **Google API** that returns a JSON containing the profile based on an access_token. The URL is:
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=ya29.1.AADtN_VALuuUTBm8ENfNTz8s...

And the response is:

```
{
    "id": "111223344556677889900",
    "email": "myemail@gmail.com",
    "verified_email": true,
    "name": "My Name",
    "given_name": "My",
    "family_name": "Name",
    "link": "plus.google.com/111223344556677889900",
    "picture": "photo.jpg",
    "gender": "male",
    "locale": "en"
}
```

Some points:

**1** I want to use the Java library to avoid mounting the HTTP request, keep the google server URL, and other minor things.
**2** I don't need the authorization steps because, at this point, my method receives the access token (all the Oauth steps are done before).
**3** In this method, we don't have (and so far don't need) the client id and secret.
**4** I don't need the Google+ scope. Actually, I prefer not to go there. So far only found examples using the Plus library.

In summary, I need something in the google API Java library precisely equivalent to the HTTP request I use nowadays.

**Thank you very much in advance!**

Comment: It sounds like you are referring to Google+ API, in which case I suggest you modify the title and tags to reflect that.

Comment: Hi, Tom. Actually I wouldnt like to use the Google+ API. I can get the user basic information without G+ API just making a HTTP request to the Google API (not +). The point is: how to do the same using the Java lib (avoiding keeping the google api url).

Comment: Not sure i follow, but note that the google java client library includes an http library that is equivalent to java http library.  On gae it wraps urlfetch.  Either are suitable for formulating and executing simple http requests.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I hope this helps

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(accessToken);   
 Oauth2 oauth2 = new Oauth2.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credential).setApplicationName(
          "Oauth2").build();
 Userinfoplus userinfo = oauth2.userinfo().get().execute();
 userinfo.toPrettyString();
```

Comment: Helped a lot! Exactly what I need. Thank you very much @aswin !

Comment: just complementing... I had to add the following dependency:
`<dependency> 
   <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId> 
   <artifactId>google-api-services-oauth2</artifactId> 
   <version>v2-rev65-1.17.0-rc</version> 
</dependency>`

Comment: I got this working but the email always returning null, any idea?

Comment: @geek you have to request the `com.google.api.services.oauth2.Oauth2Scopes.USERINFO_EMAIL` scope to access the email address.

Comment: Where do I get the `accessToken` from?

Answer (score 2):

Complementing with more info, since I don't have enough reputation to comment on the above answer:

After adding

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-oauth2</artifactId>     
    <version>v2-rev65-1.17.0-rc</version>
</dependency>
```

to your `pom.xml` file, the following line

```java
Oauth2 oauth2 = new Oauth2.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credential).setApplicationName("Oauth2").build();
```

could raise "JacksonFactory cannot be resolved to a type", and if this happens, you can replace it with `new GsonFactory()` (from [com.google.api.client.json.gson](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-http-client/latest/com.google.api.client.json.gson)), and it'll work.

Now, about how to get an `accessToken`: it comes inside `com.google.auth.oauth2.UserCredentials` ([com.google.auth.oauth2.UserCredentials](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-auth-library/latest/com.google.auth.oauth2.UserCredentials)), which you can get by calling `com.google.auth.oauth2.UserAuthorizer.getCredentialsFromCode`.

You can build a `UserAuthorizer` by calling

```java
UserAuthorizer
    .newBuilder()
    .setClientId(ClientId.of(<client id>, <client secret>))
    .setScopes(<scopes>)
    .build()
```

You can get the `<client id>` and the `<client secret>` by reading the [OAuth Client ID file created on your google cloud project dashboard](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en) under [credentials](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials).

And lastly, an example of how to read the file using `com.google.auth.oauth2.ClientId`:

```java
ClientId parsedClient = ClientId.fromStream(new FileInputStream("key.json"))
```

I'm a bit late here, but I hope this helps someone.